# a "+" sign in email address

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to submit an email address with a "`+`" sign and validate in on server. But server receives email like "`aaa+bbb@mail.com`" as "`aaa bbb@mail.com`".

I send all data as POST request with following code

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", url, @"/signUp"]];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&email=%@&userName=%@&password=%@",
                      user.email, 
                      user.userName, 
                      user.password];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

NSData* data = [self sendRequest:url postData:postData];
```

post variable before encoding has value

```
&email=aaa+bbb@gmail.coma&userName=Asdfasdfadsfadsf&password=sdfasdf
```

after encoding it is same

```
&email=aaa+bbb@gmail.coma&userName=Asdfasdfadsfadsf&password=sdfasdf
```

Method I use to send request looks like following code:

```
-(id) sendRequest:(NSURL*) url postData:(NSData*)postData {
    // Create request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *urlResponse;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:nil];

    [request release];

    return data;
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you might want to look into NSString's `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

Comment: @greg: Wow, that’s a method name.

Answer (score 6):

The email, user name and password need to be escaped by `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&email=%@&userName=%@&password=%@",
                  [user.email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                  ...
```

However, this won't escape the `+` since it is a valid URL character. You may use the more sophiscated `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, or for simplicity, just replace all `+` by `%2B`:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&email=%@&userName=%@&password=%@",
                  [[user.email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"], ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` is being unescaped as a space by the HTTP server.

You need to escape the `+` as `%2B` by calling `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`

Answer (score 0):

You need to urlencode the plus sign. It must become `%2B` for the receiver to think it's a plus sign.